# Chakra UI gives wrong font

Tags: css, next.js, chakra-ui

So I'm trying to use the M Plus Rounded 1c font following chakra ui direction https://chakra-ui.com/community/recipes/using-fonts, but the for some reason chakra ui does not change the font. It shows on the body that the font was right but they display some font like Times New Roman

```
import Layout from "./layout";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import theme from "./theme";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const theme = extendTheme({
  fonts: {
    body: `'M PLUS Rounded 1c'`,
  },
});

export default theme;
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you load the font (file) itself?

Answer (score 0):

You're really close! Your theme is being set up correctly, you just need to import the font file that you're wanting to use.

All the code below was taken from Chakra UI's documentation on adding fonts to your app [here](https://chakra-ui.com/community/recipes/using-fonts).

One option you can do is to add the font import to your App component directly like this. Which is probably the route you'd want to go if you're only adding one. The documentation does have an example of adding multiple font types if you're wanting to go that route.

```
import '@fontsource/raleway/400.css'
import '@fontsource/open-sans/700.css'

import {
  ChakraProvider,
  Container,
  Stack,
  Heading,
  Text,
} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import theme from './theme'

const App = () => ()
```

You just need to make sure you're accessing the font from a file or npm package like this one.

`npm i @fontsource/m-plus-rounded-1c`